# It does not create an account in the database

Tags: php, ipb

I changed from IPS 3 to IPS 4 and can not create a user account with PHP.

This is for a new Linux server, running MySQL 5, PHP 7.3.1 and Nginx. The engine is IPS 4.4.3.

```php
require_once('init.php');

$member = new \IPS\Member;
$member->real_name = 'Test php';
$member->encryptedPassword('test');
$member->save();
?>

Print: Something went wrong. Please try again.
```

Comment: Maybe you have logs that would tell you what that something actually is? Sitting here I can't tell.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does that "engine" contain any methods to use enhanced logging?

Comment: Logs are missing. Framework guide: https://invisioncommunity.com/4docs/advanced-usage/development/working-with-members-r179/